# Splitting a sentence into words

Tags: string

This question already has an answer here:
Read file line by line 4 answers
How can i take a string input that is a sentence and separate the words by white spaces. If someone enters "cat in the yard" how can I separate these words and manipulate them individually.

I'm only supposed to use functions from string library though. I'm pretty sure I need to use the `{.find(" ")}` function because I can easily find spaces with it.

I think a for loop might also be helpful but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: have you tried anything so far? start with something, perhaps search for an answer on google, too -- lots of links to other, possibly similar stackoverflow questions.

Comment: At least mention the programming language.

Comment: I'm doing it in c++, I've tried to loop through the sentence but I that doesn't loop Through the individual words. I think I need 2 for loops though

Answer (score 0):

Tutorial to read file here : https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/

You'll have each line in the String "line".
To get each word, do this :

```
String line  = "cat in the yard";
    String[] words = line.split(" ");
    for (String word : words) {
        System.out.println(word);
    }
}
```